# maven copy a particular dependency jar to a specific directory in the .war file

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I am trying out a Simple Java Web Start project based on the Oracle Tutorial. I am using maven to package it as a webapp and deploy it to application server. The full source code is available here

https://github.com/KiranMohan/dynamic-tree-javaws-sample-project

The maven project structure is like

```
parent  
|--lib
|--webapp
```

The webapp module is a maven war module. It is required to package lib.jar at the root of webapp.war. NOT under WEB-INF/lib.

How to achieve this in maven?

Comment: I cant help you with the signing part but since your point 1 breaks the maven convention regarding the file structure of the packaging type `war` i dont see any other option than to move the library to the webabbs-target destination (`/target`) directly using for example the `maven-resources-plugin`. You would want to apply the goal `copy-resources` to a phase earlier than `package` to have said `jar` in the `war`'s root afterwards.

Comment: There is a Jarsigner Plugin also which would kick in before the package phase as well. I will quickly add you a sample configuration of the copy part - for sake of readabillity in the form of a answer)

Comment: I removed the second part of question on jarsigning. Will add a new question for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found that the right way to do this is to use the maven-dependency-plugin. 
Since "lib.jar" is not used in the compile phase of "webapp" module, it is only a package time dependency. Using maven-dependency-plugin, I can copy lib.jar to any required directory during the prepare-package phase. The maven-war package would then include the lib.jar in the .war package.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>[ group id ]</groupId>
                        <artifactId>[artifact id]</artifactId>
                        <version>[ version ]</version>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}</outputDirectory>                                 
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
                <!-- other configurations here -->
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Update:**
There is a webstart-maven-plugin that does a better job of packaging javaws applications. See my sample project
https://github.com/KiranMohan/dynamic-tree-javaws-sample-project
for details

Comment: Indeed - **IF** `lib.jar` is a Maven artifact this is a better way since it will be consumed from the repository. (The copy mechanismn however is the same). Note that i have my doubts you acctually need to do this - my guess is you require `lib.jar` (resp. the according maven artefact) as a dependency of either `scope` `runtime` or `provided`. I too assume that you could store `lib.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder and that you just have troubles loading content from within that directory. May i ask you about the purpose of `lib.jar` and why it must reside in the root of the `war`?

Comment: As javaws application, lib.jar needs to downloaded by client and should acessible over the network, i.e., the jar needs to be made publicly available by the Application server. Now Jboss seems to hide anything under WEB-INF directory. So I put in the root of the .war file.

Comment: [How can I get this file into the `.jar` file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052996/how-to-build-single-jar-and-keep-dependencies-intact) in the end?

Comment: I received the following error when running this: 'artifactItems is not recognized as a maven tag'

Answer (score 1):

Well how i said in the comments for sake of readability here is a part of the answer:

Since Maven will always store the dependencies of a web project under its `WEB-INF/lib` folder by default i (i am no Maven expert ...) would try to place my `lib.jar` inside the `/target` folder of the project before the phase `package` is executed.

**NOTE:** I havent tried it out so you will have to adjust the paths - expecially the output path so your `lib.jar` is placed properly to be packed into the root of the `war` (e.g. if you open your `war` there will be a `lib.jar` next to folders such as `WEB-INF`).

```
<!--
lets assume the root of my project would be under C:/devjba/projectX this equals the maven
variable ${project.basedir}.

from there the output-directory would be located under C:/devjba/projectX/target which equals the
maven variable ${project.build.directory}. This is the location a .war would be placed in after
the build

lets assume the required jar lib.jar is located under C:/devjba/projectX/misc which would equal to
the expression: ${project.basedir}/misc
-->

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>foo</id>
            <!-- may adjust to another phase before package but make sure your plugin is bound to a phase
            because otherwise it wont be invoked during build! Now its bound to the first phase of the
            default lifecycle for packaging type war -->
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <!-- use the copy-resources goal of this plugin - it will copy resources :) -->
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <!-- this points to /target of the current project, you may adjust it to wherever it must be placed to be packed into the root of the war (just try&error) -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this points to a folder /misc under the project root where we expect the lib.jar -->
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/misc</directory>
                        <!-- unless you specify what to include anything of the above directory will be included -->
                        <includes>
                            <include>lib.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

As i said i have no experience in signing JARs at all but there is a plugin called `maven-jarsigner-plugin` which i guess will do the job (i would sign it, then move it, then package the war) with a manual - i recomend you try to configure it according to my "example configuration of the `maven-resource-plugin` and post a new question directly containing your two plugin configurations. Dont forget to link to this question in that case. And also leave this question open so someone with a better approach may correct my way).

Comment: Would this work for me in order to accomplish [build a single jar with additional war files as resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42052996/how-to-build-single-jar-and-keep-dependencies-intact)?